# Insert Data from text box to database asp.net MVC4

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

i am using an MVC4 view page and i am trying to insert data to my MS SQL database from text boxes by clicking a button. I am struggling to do so and i guess that the problem is "con.open()",but i do not know where to declare it. Here is my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<script runat="server">

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GreenEnergyConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);

   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into CUSTOMER values ('"+TextBox2.Text+"', '"+TextBox3.Text+"', '"+TextBox4.Text+"','"+TextBox5.Text+"','"+TextBox6.Text+"', '"+TextBox7.Text+"', '"+TextBox8.Text+"')",con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    TextBox8.Text = "";
    TextBox7.Text = "";
    TextBox6.Text = "";
    TextBox5.Text = "";
    TextBox4.Text = "";
    TextBox3.Text = "";
    TextBox2.Text = "";

}
```

And at my web.config i declared the following:

```
<add namespace="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
<add namespace="System.Configuration"/>
```

Comment: believe me, you can do it better using MVC?

Comment: I guess you mean by using a web form will be much easier right? So far i used only MVC's. I tried this with a web form but i am getting errors when i run it,i think i have to update something?how?where?

Comment: That is a SQL injection attack waiting to happen.

Comment: No what i meant is, you should make use of your controller and model.

Comment: I am using my controller but not my model though. Trying the same thing with a web form i am getting the following error:
The view at '~/Views/Home/WebForm1.aspx' must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage<TModel>, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl<TModel>. 
These might be silly questions but this is my first app

Answer (score 0):

what you have above is not MVC. it's webforms. the `<script runat="server">` tag is a dead give away. this code should be in a controller action. when the user clicks HTML submit in the HTML form MVC will route the request to the controller action. within this action you will write the code to execute sql.

I would highly recommend Razor over webforms syntax. It's much cleaner and easier to work with.

Comment: Right,i got it but i do not know how to use razors and my time is very limited. Can you give me a complete solution to this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think there are so many wrong or at least substandar things in your approach that is difficult to help you directly. Instead I think I could guide you in what MVC means:

1. In an MVC fwk you have a Model, a View and a Controller.
2. In your controller you instanciates a Model, populates it... and call the View.
3. When you have a form, you normally need 2 controller actions:  one for the display of the view, and other when you submit the form.
4. When you submit the form you will receive the model... in MVC you don't have access to form fields as in WebForms  (with your TextBox1.Text and the runat="server" it is obvious you are not working with MVC correctly).

Aside of that, adding code to access the database directly from the view is wrong in several ways... I mean, technically you can do it, but you are asking for trouble.

I strongly suggest you to download an example MVC 3 or 4 application, to undestand the concepts and do some tests. I recomend you using Razor for your views.